# CSS: set and maintain aspect ratio of DIV on window resize

Tags: css, resize

http://jsfiddle.net/NN7B9/

```
.indexmenu1 {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    background:#e7d778;
    }
.indexmenu2 {
    height:300px;
    padding:30px;
    border:1px solid #dea9b8;
    font-family:'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman';
    font-size:20px;
    color:#000;
    }
```

Fiddle up top, edit that please. I want to set an aspect ratio for these divs and maintain that when the window resizes. How do I do that?

Comment: what did you tried and didn't work?

Comment: just provide a width and height as a percentage, and it will keep that ratio (relative to the containing element's dimensions)

Answer (score 0):

you could do width as a percentage and do display:inline-block;